# How can I append an argument to different kind of URLs?

Tags: php, url

I want to add `_token=lwkemrf034iofk34` to these URLs:

```
$url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/search?q=something";
$url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/search/23"
```

As you see, those URL have different types. For the first one I have to do:

```
$url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/search?q=something";
$token = _token=lwkemrf034iofk34;
$final_url = $url . "&" . $token;
```

And for the second one:

```
$url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/search/23";
$token = _token=lwkemrf034iofk34;
$final_url = $url . "?" . $token;
```

Is there any flexible approach to detect the URL type and append that token to it?

Comment: See [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and  [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: http_build_query() is a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

if (empty($query))
  $final_url = $url . '?' . $token;
else
  $final_url = $url . '&' . $token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helpl you out. Here we are gathering complete query string parameters, `implode`ing with `&` and then appending them to URL.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/search/23";
echo addQueryParams($url, "_token=name");
function addQueryParams($url,$paramsString)
{
    $result=explode('?',$url);
    $url=$result[0];
    unset($result[0]);
    $result[]=$paramsString;
    return $url.="?".  implode("&", $result);
}
```